# Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 501

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, proxy, mechanize, tor

Using Tor on Ubuntu and trying to proxify Mechanize

```
$ tor
Apr 15 11:40:10.024 [notice] Tor v0.2.4.21 (git-c5a648cc6f218339) running on Linux with Libevent 2.0.19-stable and OpenSSL 1.0.1c.
Apr 15 11:40:10.024 [notice] Tor can't help you if you use it wrong! Learn how to be safe at https://www.torproject.org/download/download#warning
Apr 15 11:40:10.024 [notice] Read configuration file "/etc/tor/torrc".
Apr 15 11:40:10.029 [notice] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9050
Apr 15 11:40:10.029 [warn] Could not bind to 127.0.0.1:9050: Address already in use. Is Tor already running?
Apr 15 11:40:10.029 [warn] Failed to parse/validate config: Failed to bind one of the listener ports.
Apr 15 11:40:10.029 [err] Reading config failed--see warnings above.

agent = Mechanize.new
agent.set_proxy('127.0.0.1', 9050)
agent.user_agent_alias = 'Mac Safari'
agent.get("http://www.linkedin.com/in/username")
=> Mechanize::ResponseCodeError: 501 => Net::HTTPNotImplemented for http://www.linkedin.com/in/username -- unhandled response
from /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize/http/agent.rb:306:in `fetch'
from /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/mechanize-2.7.2/lib/mechanize.rb:432:in `get'
from (irb):5
from /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:90:in `start'
from /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /home/tristan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.1/gems/railties-4.0.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:62:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:4:in `require'
from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Any ideas to how to solve this? Having a really hard time trying to proxify this! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The proxy that you are setting in mechanize is an HTTP proxy and not a socks5 proxy. Tor uses socks proxy and not HTTP proxy. By default it opens a socks proxy on port 9050.

I would suggest you to use [privoxy](http://www.privoxy.org/faq/misc.html#TOR) which let you pass the requests on socks proxy on port 9050.